# CMake ninja custom target used as pre-build command modifies the files but ninja see the change of the depndecies during next build

Tags: cmake, build, dependencies, ninja

I run some command before the actual build

```
add_custom_target("${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE}" 
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_UPDATE} "-p" "-x" -f ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${MAIN_PATH}/${BOARD_NAME}/${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE}
    )

add_dependencies(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} "${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE}" )
```

When I build first time (the project was build before)

```
>------ Build started: Project: CMakeLists, Configuration: Debug ------
  [1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\Piotr\git\gPIMS-EG\out\build\IoT-Debug && C:\Users\Piotr\git\gPIMS-EG\stm-libs\pc-exe\buildnum.exe -p -x -f C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/src/EG/BuildID.h"
  Build number file used:C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/src/EG/BuildID.h
  Build file updated: Build Number: 22 DateCode: 0x1d6d

Build succeeded.
```

BuildID.h file was modified and saved. Modification date is set correctly.

On the second build it behaves correctly

```
>------ Build started: Project: CMakeLists, Configuration: Debug ------
  [1/4] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\Piotr\git\gPIMS-EG\out\build\IoT-Debug && C:\Users\Piotr\git\gPIMS-EG\stm-libs\pc-exe\buildnum.exe -p -x -f C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/src/EG/BuildID.h"
  Build number file used:C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/src/EG/BuildID.h
  Build file updated: Build Number: 23 DateCode: 0x1d6d
  [2/4] C:\PROGRA~2\Atollic\TRUEST~1.0\ARMTools\bin\AR097D~1.EXE -DALLOW_SOFTWARE_BKPTS=1 -DARM_MATH_CM4 -DBOOTLOADER_VERSION=1 -DCOMPILE_FOR_EG=1 -DDEBUGFILEWRITE=1 -DDEBUG_RUN_WITHOUT_CHECKS=1 -DFORCE_CUBE_USB -DHSE_VALUE=8000000UL -DSLOWSPIDEBUG=0 -DSTM32L -DSTM32L476xx -DSTM32L4xx -DUSE_EMBEDDED_PHY=1 -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT -DUSE_FULL_LL_DRIVER="" -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_SWOTRACE=1 -DUSE_USB_OTG_FS=1 -DUSE_USB_OTG_HS=1 -D_DEBUG=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D__USE_SIMPLE_SWO=0 -I../../../src -I../../../src/EG -I../../../src/ZM -I../../../src/inc -I../../../stm-libs/inc -I../../../stm-libs/Drivers -I../../../stm-libs/Services -I../../../stm-libs/Services/Utils -I../../../stm-libs/RTOS/Source/include -I../../../stm-libs/RTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CMSIS/Include -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CryptoLib/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CryptoLib/Inc/RNG -I../../../stm-libs/drivers/USBD -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Device/Class/CDC/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Device/Class/MSC_HID/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Device/Core/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/ports/STM32F4x7 -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/ports/STM32F4x7/arch -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/src -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/src/include -I../../../stm-libs/drivers/USBH -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/AUDIO/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/CDC/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/HID/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/MSC/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/MTP/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Core/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/Template/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/ports/STM32F4x7/FreeRTOS -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/misc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/FatFs/src -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/littleFS -I../../../stm-libs/Apps -I../../../stm-libsApps/SeqZM -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/libc_e -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries -I../../../stm-hal-l4/Inc/Legacy -I../../../stm-hal-l4/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Apps/Other -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Og -g3 -T"C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/src/EG/startup/EG.ld" -L"C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/stm-libs/Libraries/CryptoLib" -lSTM32CryptographicV3.0.0_CM4_GCC_FPU -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -Wl,-Map="EG.map" -static -Wl,-u,Reset_Handler  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--defsym=malloc_getpagesize_P=0x80 -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/GCEG-FW.dir/stm-libs/Apps/common/SC_Ver.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\GCEG-FW.dir\stm-libs\Apps\common\SC_Ver.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/GCEG-FW.dir/stm-libs/Apps/common/SC_Ver.c.obj   -c ../../../stm-libs/Apps/common/SC_Ver.c
  In file included from ../../../stm-libs/Apps/common/SC_Ver.c:9:0:
C:\Users\Piotr\git\gPIMS-EG\stm-libs\Drivers\CAN-COB.h(267,2): warning GF07C7A44: #warning added to compile BP to change [-Wcpp]
   #warning added to compile BP to change
    ^~~~~~~
  [3/4] C:\PROGRA~2\Atollic\TRUEST~1.0\ARMTools\bin\AR097D~1.EXE -DALLOW_SOFTWARE_BKPTS=1 -DARM_MATH_CM4 -DBOOTLOADER_VERSION=1 -DCOMPILE_FOR_EG=1 -DDEBUGFILEWRITE=1 -DDEBUG_RUN_WITHOUT_CHECKS=1 -DFORCE_CUBE_USB -DHSE_VALUE=8000000UL -DSLOWSPIDEBUG=0 -DSTM32L -DSTM32L476xx -DSTM32L4xx -DUSE_EMBEDDED_PHY=1 -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT -DUSE_FULL_LL_DRIVER="" -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_SWOTRACE=1 -DUSE_USB_OTG_FS=1 -DUSE_USB_OTG_HS=1 -D_DEBUG=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D__USE_SIMPLE_SWO=0 -I../../../src -I../../../src/EG -I../../../src/ZM -I../../../src/inc -I../../../stm-libs/inc -I../../../stm-libs/Drivers -I../../../stm-libs/Services -I../../../stm-libs/Services/Utils -I../../../stm-libs/RTOS/Source/include -I../../../stm-libs/RTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CMSIS/Include -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CryptoLib/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/CryptoLib/Inc/RNG -I../../../stm-libs/drivers/USBD -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Device/Class/CDC/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Device/Class/MSC_HID/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Device/Core/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/ports/STM32F4x7 -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/ports/STM32F4x7/arch -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/src -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/src/include -I../../../stm-libs/drivers/USBH -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/AUDIO/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/CDC/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/HID/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/MSC/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/MTP/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Core/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/USB/Host/Class/Template/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/lwip/ports/STM32F4x7/FreeRTOS -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/misc -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/FatFs/src -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/littleFS -I../../../stm-libs/Apps -I../../../stm-libsApps/SeqZM -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries/libc_e -I../../../stm-libs/Libraries -I../../../stm-hal-l4/Inc/Legacy -I../../../stm-hal-l4/Inc -I../../../stm-libs/Apps/Other -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Og -g3 -T"C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/src/EG/startup/EG.ld" -L"C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/stm-libs/Libraries/CryptoLib" -lSTM32CryptographicV3.0.0_CM4_GCC_FPU -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -Wl,-Map="EG.map" -static -Wl,-u,Reset_Handler  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--defsym=malloc_getpagesize_P=0x80 -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/GCEG-FW.dir/stm-libs/Apps/WaveMC3/waveMC3SeqGUI.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\GCEG-FW.dir\stm-libs\Apps\WaveMC3\waveMC3SeqGUI.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/GCEG-FW.dir/stm-libs/Apps/WaveMC3/waveMC3SeqGUI.c.obj   -c ../../../stm-libs/Apps/WaveMC3/waveMC3SeqGUI.c
  In file included from ../../../stm-libs/Drivers/CAN-G3M.h:31:0,
                   from ../../../stm-libs/Drivers/ioCmd.h:12,
                   from ../../../stm-libs/Services/srvCmd.h:9,
                   from ../../../src/EG/../ZM/zmServices.h:10,
                   from ../../../src/EG/ourServices.h:12,
                   from ../../../stm-libs/Apps/WaveMC3/waveMC3SeqGUI.c:5:
C:\Users\Piotr\git\gPIMS-EG\stm-libs\Drivers\CAN-COB.h(267,2): warning GF07C7A44: #warning added to compile BP to change [-Wcpp]
   #warning added to compile BP to change
    ^~~~~~~
  [4/4] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\Atollic\TRUEST~1.0\ARMTools\bin\AR097D~1.EXE -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Og -g3 -T"C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/src/EG/startup/EG.ld" -L"C:/Users/Piotr/git/gPIMS-EG/stm-libs/Libraries/CryptoLib" -lSTM32CryptographicV3.0.0_CM4_GCC_FPU -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -Wl,-Map="EG.map" -static -Wl,-u,Reset_Handler  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--defsym=malloc_getpagesize_P=0x80 -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g   @CMakeFiles\GCEG-FW.rsp  -o GCEG-FW.elf  && cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\Piotr\git\gPIMS-EG\out\build\IoT-Debug && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.3.0\ARMTools\bin\arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy.exe" GCEG-FW.elf --output-target=binary GCEG-FW.bin -j .isr_vector -j .VERSION_INFO -j .text -j .rodata -j .ARM.extab -j .ARM -j .preinit_array -j .init_array -j .fini_array -j .data -j .RAM_VectorTable -j .RAM_DATAfunctions -j .RAM_functions -v && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.3.0\ARMTools\bin\arm-atollic-eabi-size.exe" GCEG-FW.elf --format=Berkeley""
  copy from `GCEG-FW.elf' [elf32-littlearm] to `GCEG-FW.bin' [binary]
     text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
   210428     36680   54020  301128   49848 GCEG-FW.elf

Build succeeded.
```

It looks like ninja is checking dependencies before the actual build starts and ignores meanwhile file changed. Is there any way to force cmake/ninja to recheck dependecies after custom target is build (ie prgram that thenges the build is run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks like ninja is checking dependencies before the actual build starts and ignores meanwhile file change

Hey! Yes. Because DEPFILEs from C source files are generated *at the same time* as they are compiled, cmake has no way to know beforehand which file depends on which. It would have to do two passes - first to get dependencies and then to compile (which would be a nice feature, but actually hard to implement). It happens in one pass during compilation (`-MD -MT` flags), so cmake has no way of knowing that one file depends on that header. I also advise:

- Do not modify files in your source tree. Keep all changes in BINARY_DIR.
- Do not modify files. Generate new files. It's easier and generally, less state = less problems.

Try it such:

```
# Inside binary_dir
set(PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen/buildid_gen.h)
# Add #include <buildid_gen.h> to your buildid.h
add_custom_command(
     OUTPUT ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE}
     COMMAND ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_UPDATE} "-p" "-x" -f ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE}
     DEPENDS ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_UPDATE}
)
add_custom_target(buildid_gen
    COMMENT "Yooohooo!"
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE}
)
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE} ${some_other_sources})
target_add_include_directories(${EXECTABLE_NAME} PUBLIC
     # add include directory, so that buildid_gen is found
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gen
)
# this *helps*
add_dependencies(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} buildid_gen)
```

> Is there any way to force cmake/ninja to recheck dependecies after custom target is build (ie prgram that thenges the build is run).

The *real proper way* ™ would be to manually track all files that depend on the file (you could think of `grep -l '#include <buildid_gen.h>` to get the list files) and communicate to cmake the dependency relation:

```
add_source_file_properties(${sources_that_include_buildid_gen} PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${PROJECT_BUILD_NUM_FILE})
```

Tracking dependencies is easier if you use a runtime interface (ie. `long get_build_id();`) cause then only one `.c` file that implements the interface will depend on the generated file.
There are also some projects that are compiled in two passes because of such dependencies, you have to first `cmake .. --target buildid_gen` and then `cmake .. --target actually_compile` each time you compile.
Also maybe `execute_process` is more appropriate if the file is setup once per build.